# Is there a better way to see if customers took a 'break period' in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to see how many customers have returned after two years of dormancy. I also have to join two tables with older (before 2008) and newer purchasing data (after 2008). Each table has the same columns but different records.

For example, if Bill made a purchase on July 1, 2010 and didn't purchase anything else until July 1, 2012, he would be counted. Each purchase date has its own column.

I've been suggested to try out the code shown below, but it is super slow (I have a lot of records). I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

(I am using Redshift)

```
FROM (SELECT s.cust_id, s.purchase_date,
             LAG(s.purchase_date) OVER (PARTITION BY s.cust_id ORDER BY s.purchase_date,) as prev_pd
      FROM newer_purchase_data s JOIN older_purchase_data l on s.cust_id = l.cust_id
     ) t
WHERE DATEDIFF(days, prev_pd, s.purchase_date) >= 730  /* 2 years in days */
;
```

Comment: I'm confused by your example.  Isn't 2010-07-01 before 2012-07-01?  So Bill necessarily has an earlier purchase.  Sample data and desired results would also really help.  It is not clear how purchase data is split across two tables.

Comment: why is this slow? can you give some table sizes, cluster sizes? how long does it take? what is the distribution on both tables (ideally should be cust_id) - do you have multiple rows for each cust_id on both tables?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, in order for someone to be dormant for two years, they need an earlier purchase. Bill made a purchase in July 2010 and didn't buy anything again until July 2012 (hence the two year dormancy period). The data was given to me across the two tables. Each table has the same columns; only the records are different.

Comment: @JonScott after 10 minutes, I just canceled it. There is one column for cust_id on each of the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently you are causing a many to many join ( i think)  - which causes your inefficiency.

Try this structure for your query

```
select *
FROM (SELECT cust_id, purchase_date::timestamp,
             LAG(purchase_date::timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY purchase_date) as prev_pd
          FROM 
           (select cust_id,purchase_date from older_purchase_data 
            union all
            select cust_id,purchase_date from newer_purchase_data 
           ) as x
         ) t
    WHERE DATEDIFF('day', prev_pd, purchase_date) >= 730  /* 2 years in days */
```

Comment: From yours... SQL Error [500310] [42601]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "FROM" 
Position: 1;

Comment: sorry i missed the select * from the first line (just like you did on your example in your question)